# How to get an value from a bootstrap dropdown menu (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, websocket

I'm setting up a webserver and I want to send the selected values from bootstrap dropdown menus peer websocket.

I'm already tried to set an value for the selected items with 
data-value="some value" and value="some value". And try to get them with an jQuery.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle config_btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="btn_baud">
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <u1 class="dropdown-menu" id="baudrate">
        <li><a href="#">250 kBit/s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">500 kBit/s</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">1 MBit/s</a></li>
    </u1>
</div>
```

Show the selected value in the Dropdown menu button:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#baudrate a").click(function(){
        $("#btn_baud").text($(this).text());
    });
});
```

Get the selected text from the Dropdown menu:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#baudrate li a").click(function() {
        baudrate = $(this).html();
    });
});
```

I'm able to get the selected text from the Dropdown menu but I can't get an value.

When I try to set an value like:

```
<li data-value="250"><a href="#">250 kBit/s</a></li>
<li><a data-value="250" href="#">250 kBit/s</a></li>
```

I can't get it with `.value()` in my jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not value its data.

https://api.jquery.com/data/

```
$(element).data('value');
```

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn dropdown-toggle config_btn" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" id="btn_baud">
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <u1 class="dropdown-menu" id="baudrate">
        <li><input type="hidden" value="250"/><a href="#">250 kBit/s</a></li>
        <li><input type="hidden" value="500"/><a href="#">500 kBit/s</a></li>
        <li><input type="hidden" value="1"/><a href="#">1 MBit/s</a></li>
    </u1>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#baudrate li a").click(function() {
            baudrate = $(this).parent().find('input').val();
            alert(baudrate);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It will be better if you could explain your answer.

Comment: Include inside <li> hidden input with the value you need. Inside js you are looking for this input tag and taking it value outside. In this case li tag works as container.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What is the Advantage of this method in comparison to the other way?

Comment: This way of getting a content from your DOM by clicking an element is very useful, first of all, you can create a dynamic page by getting the full data once. You can put it inside many hidden inputs and get them visible by using of js. It seems like a "worm" - you're initialize an event (entrance hole) and get any content from your active page(exit hole).
In this way very easy to change active page(change values, text, append or remove elements) by using only js.

Comment: And ofcourse it very useful while working with data tables. The last one my data table was upgraded by dynamic datepickers and loading modal windows only for selected row.